# Kinect with c# to control an avatar?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opengl, kinect

For my university final project I want to make a program that allows me to control my avatar using the Kinect.

I have already got the Kinect to track the user head and hands, but what can I do to get the Kinect to work with an avatar?

Is there any tutotrials or some sort of guidance out there? Can't really find anything concrete

Comment: Where have you looked so far? StackOverflow works best when you describe what you've already done and where you're stuck. "Where can I find a library to do x?" is too open of a question to be answered well here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple of samples I would recommend for what you want:

- [Avateering Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131041.aspx) (Demonstrates how to use the Joint Orientation API )
- [Skeleton Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855381.aspx) (Demo's capturing skeletons and displaying them on screen)
- [How to Draw a skeleton](http://elbruno.com/2013/12/20/kinectone-howto-draw-a-body-aka-skeleton-using-kinectsdk-v2/) (if  you are using Kinect V2)

Comment: For the Avateering sample , in the kinect chooser class when i try to build and run the application i get the error " Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Is this due to my Kinect not functioning properly or ?

Comment: @JaphetWilliams its hard to say without code or a callstack.  Usually this refers to a variable that was set to null and shouldn't have been.

Comment: the call stack says false for the boolean value for things such as last status it will say not powered on , but the kinect is powered on and plugged in